# Flask Password Hashing Issue: Why Does 'Login1' Always Report 'Password is incorrect' While 'Login2' Works?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I'm encountering a peculiar issue with password hashing in my Flask API, which utilizes MongoDB as the database. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, logout_user
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import current_user
from bson import ObjectId, json_util
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime

# ... (omitting unrelated code)

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login_1():
    data = request.get_json()
    print('\n\n', data, '\n')
    username = data['username']
    password = data['password']
    user = users_collection.find_one({'username': username})
    if user:
        if check_password_hash(user['password_hash'], password):
            print("Password is correct.")
        else:
            print("Password is incorrect.")

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login_2():
    data = request.get_json()
    print('\n\n', data, '\n')
    username = data['username']
    password = data['password']
    user = users_collection.find_one({'username': username})
    if user:
        if check_password_hash(generate_password_hash(password, method="pbkdf2:sha256"), password):
            print("Password is correct.")
        else:
            print("Password is incorrect.")
```

The issue I'm facing is that when I use login_1, it always reports "Password is incorrect," while login_2 seems to work correctly, reporting "Password is correct."

Comment: Looking at the diff between the two methods should answer your question. Search for "password hashing". Also looking at the "unrelated code" might help.

Answer (score -1):

In the first function, you compare the password of the user in the database to the one received in the request. If it returns "password incorrect", the passwords probably don't match (you typed the wrong password).

In the second function however, you compare the hash of the request password to itself, so of course it will always return True, which will display "password is correct" even if the request password doesn't match the one in the database.

I think you made a mistake in the second function. For login, you should always compare the password from the request to the one stored in the database.